# Is there a way to check if wallet sees monerod over the LAN?

Tags: monero-wallet-cli, monerod, synchronization, connection

I have a `monerod` daemon running on a PC (IP `192.168.1.150`) and a wallet running on another PC. Sometimes all works, sometimes not and shows:

`Error: wallet failed to connect to daemon`

I use these commands to launch the programs:

```
./monerod --rpc-bind-ip 192.168.1.150 --confirm-external-bind

./monero-wallet-cli --daemon-address 192.168.1.150 --wallet-file walletname
```

So, is there a way to check the connection between daemon and wallet?

Comment: Perhaps try binding to `0.0.0.0`? It's probably a good idea then to add the `--rpc-login` flag too (use `monerod --help` & `monero-wallet-cli --help` to see the specific parameters and arguments) as well as the `--restricted-rpc` flag.

Comment: Not works. I have checked the wallet log, found this:

    `02-02 16:13:35.401     7f8ccd227b80        ERROR   net.http        contrib/epee/include/net/http_client.h:444      Unexpected recv fail
    02-02 16:13:35.401     7f8ccd227b80        ERROR   wallet.wallet2  src/wallet/wallet2.cpp:1216     !r. THROW EXCEPTION: error::no_connection_to_daemon
    02-02 16:13:35.401     7f8ccd227b80        WARN    net.http        src/wallet/wallet_errors.h:707  /DISTRIBUTION-BUILD/src/wallet/wallet2.cpp:1216:N5tools5error23no_connection_to_daemonE: no connection to daemon, request = getblocks.bin`

Comment: @dEBRUYNE I did several attempts with different combinations of parameters, all fail. I also deleted the blockchain and synced it again, the same result. The wallet reaches the daemon, but it still not working. Maybe, should I open an issue on GitHub?

Comment: That seems like a good idea. Although, it should be noted that your issue is likely caused by idiosyncratic factors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the new [0.13.0.4 Beryllium Bullet](https://downloads.getmonero.org/cli/linux64) version of the daemon and CLI software, all is working fine under Linux. No more issues.

Answer (score 0):

Try with this command:

```
./monero-wallet-cli --daemon-host 192.168.1.150 --wallet-file walletname
```

This seemed to work for me.

Comment: The same result, I'm thinking at issue related to my LAN. If I did nmap -p 18081 192.168.1.150, I get 18081/tcp open and also DNS resolution is fully working, so I don't understand the problem.